# open toolkit context menu in a list box data template on image wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a list box and within the list box data template i have a context menu that opens when i hold the list item . But what i want to do is open the context menu on tapping on an image within the list item data template . How can i achieve this as the toolkit menu is not visible from the visual tree helper . Also i don't want to remove the context menu from the data template as i require info about the selected item which is passed through the data context . is there any way to do this or should i create my own custom pop-up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open the context menu programmatically. Just add a tap event on the image control in your ListBox ItemTemplate and using XAML add the proper code exactly like you wanted to use the context menu with a button.

In the Image1_Tap event add this piece of code:

```
private void image1_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    Image image = sender as Image;
    ContextMenu contextMenu = ContextMenuService.GetContextMenu(image);
    if (contextMenu.Parent == null)
    {
        contextMenu.IsOpen = true;
    }
}
```

The XAML code would be something like this:

```
<Image>

    <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
        <toolkit:ContextMenu>
            ...
        </toolkit:ContextMenu>
    </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>

</Image>
```

Comment: thanks its working :) . I have just one doubt why are we doing the if(contextmenu.parent==null) ??

Comment: It was part of an old project, probably it was a snippet from MSDN. I remember that it occurred a problem when trying to open if it was already displayed, something like so.